Error sending emailmessage with fileattachment
We have a number of EWS integrations that started failing a few days ago that send emails with attachments.  If we skip the two lines that add file attachments, the send runs fine. This would be great, if we didn't need the attachments with the emails..
When the attachment lines are not skipped, I get an exception:
Microsoft.Exchange.WebServices.Data.ServiceResponseException
HResult=0x80131500
Message=The operation can't be performed because the item is out of date. Reload the item and try again.
Source=Mnt.Microsoft.Exchange.WebServices.Data
In researching this, I think it has to do with a stale changekey, but I am not certain.
I tried reloading the id with message.Load(new PropertySet(BasePropertySet.IdOnly)), right before the .send operation, but that throws an exception telling me that that the item does not have an id....
System.InvalidOperationException
HResult=0x80131509
Message=This operation can't be performed because this service object doesn't have an Id.
This all worked fine until the day before yesterday, nobody made any changes.
Any help would be greatly appreciated.
The code looks like this:
    private static void SendMailOAUTH(MemoryStream ms, string FileName, string DList, string eMailSubject, string eMailBody)
    {


        string clientId = clientidvalue;
        string clientSecret = clientsecretvalue;
        string tenantId = tenantidvalue;
        string userEmail = emailtoimpersonate;

        string authority = $"https://login.microsoftonline.com/{tenantId}";
        string[] scopes = { "https://outlook.office365.com/.default" };

        IConfidentialClientApplication app = ConfidentialClientApplicationBuilder
            .Create(clientId)
            .WithClientSecret(clientSecret)
            .WithAuthority(new Uri(authority))
            .Build();

        Microsoft.Identity.Client.AuthenticationResult authResult = app.AcquireTokenForClient(scopes).ExecuteAsync().Result;
        string accessToken = authResult.AccessToken;

        var credentials = new OAuthCredentials(accessToken);

        var ews = new ExchangeService
        {
            Credentials = credentials,
            ImpersonatedUserId = new ImpersonatedUserId(ConnectingIdType.SmtpAddress, userEmail),
            Url = new Uri("https://outlook.office365.com/EWS/Exchange.asmx", UriKind.Absolute)
        };

        EmailMessage serviceMail = new(ews)
        {
            Subject = eMailSubject,
            Body = eMailBody
        };
        serviceMail.Body.BodyType = BodyType.HTML;
        string[] distroList = DList.Split(',');
        foreach (string distro in distroList)
        {
            serviceMail.ToRecipients.Add(new EmailAddress(distro));
        }

        FileAttachment attachment = serviceMail.Attachments.AddFileAttachment(FileName, ms);
        attachment.ContentType = "text/plain";

        try
        {
            serviceMail.Send();
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            _ = ex.Message;
        }
        finally
        {
            ms.Dispose();
        }
    }

If we don't add the attachment, then the message sends.  I am stuck and would appreciate any help.

So a little research found this article:
Exchange Web Services - sending email error "item is out of date"
and based on that I changed the attachment and send to this:
        ms.Position = 0;
        FileAttachment attachment = serviceMail.Attachments.AddFileAttachment(FileName, ms);
        attachment.ContentType = "text/csv";

        try
        {
            serviceMail.Save(WellKnownFolderName.Drafts);
            EmailMessage draftMessage = EmailMessage.Bind(ews, serviceMail.Id);
            draftMessage.SendAndSaveCopy();
        }

And now the code seems to be working...
